# Unsupported URL scheme error, how to use "https" CRAN mirrors in R 3.2.4?

Tags: r, cran

When I run `install.packages("packagename")` I get prompted to choose a CRAN mirror.

- If I choose a https mirror the following error message comes up:

  ```
  unsupported URL scheme
  ```
- If I choose a http mirror (choice 22), installation goes on without this warning.

How do I make `install.packages()` support `https` mirrors?

I'm using a 32 bit version of R if that is of any importance.

Comment: Does [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827897-Secure-Package-Downloads-for-R) help?

Comment: Thanks I added `options(download.file.method = "libcurl")` but R complained that `download.file(method = 'libcurl') is not supported on this platform`.  The download.file help page says that `Support for method "libcurl" is optional: use capabilities("libcurl") to see if it is supported on your build. (It uses an external library of that name (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) against which R can be compiled.)`

Comment: _" In the case that it wasn’t (i.e. capabilities("libcurl") == FALSE), you can follow the directions for earlier versions of R below to configure an alternate secure method."_

Comment: Yes with `options(download.file.method = "wget")` I can now install packages from https mirrors.             Using the external command `wget` seems like a workaround. I'm still wondering how to make https downloads available natively. I have installed the `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` Debian package after installing R. Maybe I need to reinstall R. Wondering if the R installation will automatically detect that libcurl is available?

Comment: I guess you could write your `options` to an `,Rprofile` file, as the document suggests.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
install.packages("packagename", repos="http://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu")

Comment: I don't think this answer the OP's question: this corresponds to "If I choose a http mirror (choice 22), installation goes on without this warning", as the OP already knows how to do ...