# Download R and specific package as travis dependency

Tags: r, julia, travis-ci

I'm trying to set up CI for a julia package, but that also needs R and the R package 'ape'. As the julia package interacts with R. I'm having trouble setting up travis for this:

```
language: julia
os:
  - linux
  - osx
julia:
  - 0.6
notifications:
  email: false
before_install:
    # linux
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]; then sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9; fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]; then sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -s -c)/"; fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]; then sudo apt-get update -qq -y; fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "linux" ]; then sudo apt-get install git r-base r-base-dev r-recommended -y; fi

    # osx
    # faster than using homebrew/science tap
    # but no permalink to release download
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]; then wget "https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/$(wget -qO- https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/ | sed -n 's/.*href="\(R-[^"]*.pkg\)".*/\1/p' | head -n 1)"; fi
    - if [ "$TRAVIS_OS_NAME" == "osx" ]; then sudo installer -pkg R-*.pkg -target /; fi

    - mkdir -p mkdir $HOME/R/library
    - echo 'R_LIBS_USER="~/R/library"' >  $HOME/.Renviron
    - echo 'options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="https://cloud.r-project.org/")))' > .Rprofile
    - Rscript -e 'install.packages("ape")'
after_success:
  - julia -e 'cd(Pkg.dir("BioBridgeR")); Pkg.add("Coverage"); using Coverage; Codecov.submit(process_folder())'
  - julia -e 'cd(Pkg.dir("BioBridgeR")); Pkg.add("Documenter"); include(joinpath("docs", "make.jl"))'
```

So in the before_install section, I download R.
Next I set up a local R package library, and set it in a .Renviron file, and then try to set a .Rprofile file with the default cran mirror to use.
Then I run Rscript to download the package.

However this does not  work in practice, there is some error about the URL scheme:

```
$ Rscript -e 'install.packages("ape")'
Installing package into ‘/home/travis/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib:
  unsupported URL scheme
Warning message:
package ‘ape’ is not available (for R version 3.2.5)
```

How do I correctly install R and R packages as a dependency for a project that is not itself R (language: r)?

Comment: I always install `R` packages from terminal like so: `sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('devtools', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""`. Try using `'http://cran.rstudio.com/'` as argument for *repos* and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: Hi Gregor, using http://cran.rstudio.com/ worked! If you want to add that as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: I'm not sure this was actually the problem tough. This might also be an issue with [https mirrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550221/unsupported-url-scheme-error-how-to-use-https-cran-mirrors-in-r-3-2-4). If you could try installing with `repos='http://cloud.r-project.org/'` again, this could improve the quality of the answer a lot.

Comment: Since you are using julia, you can do `julia -e 'Pkg.add("Conda"); using Conda; Conda.add("r-ape")'.`. `R` is installed into `Conda.PREFIX`